# How to read a text file that can be any length into separate string and integer variables in python?

Tags: python, variables, input, text, integer

There is a data.txt text file in the following format (the length of the text file can be any length):

```
Start 111 139
A 122 155
B 133 217
C 144 223
Finish
```

The delimiter character between each value is a tabulator (\t), and the rows are ended with enters (\n). I would like to put each value into a separate variable with the correct type (int for numbers, string for texts). The length of the text file can be any length (D, E, F... rows with different numbers can be there). In the last row there is always one word: "Finish". For the example above I would like to get 5 string variables and 8 int variables overall. The ideal output would be the following:

```
str1 = str('Start')
int1 = int(111)
int2 = int(139)
str2 = str('A')
int3 = int(122)
int4 = int(155)
str3 = str('B')
int5 = int(133)
int6 = int(217)
str4 = str('C')
int7 = int(144)
int8 = int(223)
str5 = str('Finish')
```

The name of the variables can be anything, and also the cast is not required if your method already defines the type of the variables.

For the reading in parts I tried this:

```
with open('data.txt') as file:
    lines = [line.rstrip().split('\t') for line in file]
    print(lines)
```

But it gives me lists of threes, however, I would like to create separate variables for each value dynamically. Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: What do you mean *create separate variables dynamically*? Do you mean something like `{'A': [122, 155], 'B': [133,217] ...}`? Or list of lists? Or list of dicts?

Comment: I mean to get 'A' in a string variable, '122' in an int variable, '155' in an int variable and repeat this on each row. For the example above I would get 5 string variables and 8 int variables overall.

Comment: Add what you expect as output. It is just not clear

Comment: The ideal output would be something like this: `str1 = str('Start')
int1 = int(111)
int2 = int(139)
str2 = str('A')
int3 = int(122)
int4 = int(155)
str3 = str('B')
int5 = int(133)
int6 = int(217)
str4 = str('C')
int7 = int(144)
int8 = int(223)
str5 = str('Finish')` The name of the variables can be anything, and also the cast is not required if the used method already defines the type of the variables (just wanted to express the type).

Comment: There's no (sane) way to get individual variables for each item.  It would have to be something like a dictionary or a list-of-lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example does not really make sense. But, if that is what you are looking for:

```
def conv(s):
    try:
        return ('int', int(s))
    except ValueError:
        return ('str', f"'{s}'")
    
cnt={}
with open('/tmp/file') as f:
    for line in f:
        for s in line.split():
            t=conv(s)
            cnt[t[0]]=cnt.get(t[0], 0)+1
            print(f'{t[0]}{cnt[t[0]]} = {t[0]}({t[1]})')
```

Prints:

```
str1 = str('Start')
int1 = int(111)
int2 = int(139)
str2 = str('A')
int3 = int(122)
int4 = int(155)
str3 = str('B')
int5 = int(133)
int6 = int(217)
str4 = str('C')
int7 = int(144)
int8 = int(223)
str5 = str('Finish')
```

---

DON'T try and make variables out of these! Instead, use a `dict` like so:

```
def conv(s):
    try:
        return ('int', int(s))
    except ValueError:
        return ('str', f"'{s}'")

cnt={}
data={}
with open('/tmp/file') as f:
    for line in f:
        for s in line.split():
            t=conv(s)
            cnt[t[0]]=cnt.get(t[0], 0)+1
            data[f'{t[0]}{cnt[t[0]]}'] = t[1]

>>> data
{'str1': "'Start'", 'int1': 111, 'int2': 139, 'str2': "'A'", 'int3': 122, 'int4': 155, 'str3': "'B'", 'int5': 133, 'int6': 217, 'str4': "'C'", 'int7': 144, 'int8': 223, 'str5': "'Finish'"}
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort! It gets the correct output, but I can not use the created variables later in the code. Do you think reading the input file into a dictionary would make more sense? Or how could these variables be used later in the code?

Comment: If you wanted to use *these* you would use `eval` But **don't do this! USE A DICT!**